# ios - copyWithZone:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I want to create a copy of cell object.. Following is my code but retrieving copyWithZone:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

```
  CollectionCell *cell = [cv dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"KCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

        if(kCell == nil)
        {


            cell = [self getiPadCell:indexPath cv:cv dict:dict];
            kCell = cell;
            return cell;
        }
        else
        {
            cell = [kCell copy];
            return cell;
        }
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your `CollectionCell` class should provide implementation of `copyWithZone:` method. Also it should conform to `NSCopying` protocol. Think of how you'd like to copy your cell and provide proper implementation. [This Link](http://robnapier.net/implementing-nscopying) may help you to understand it better

Comment: Andray, Actually I want to create a same copy of a cell because my cell is very dynamic and I dont want to create it on every scroll. I want to create it once and then simply change the text of the label. WHat do you think.

Comment: Why do you need to have a copy at all? It seems like you're doing something you shouldn't do

Comment: I assume that the copy will create the another same cell in memory then I will simple change the text of that cell.. Is this approach is fine?

Comment: Actually when I do all the calculations again and again, its show a jerk on scrolling .

Comment: @Arahim no that approach is not fine. What you should do is just change text on that very same cell without copying it

Comment: Actually I do calculation on collection cell. draw some graphics and borders etc etc.. which is not is xib of cell. the method "getiPadCell" did that.

Comment: so move calculations into a separate method. name it "calculation". then you can call this method from anywhere. you call it inside "getiPadCell" method. You call it also instead copying a cell. After calculation you should update the cell's appearance. This is the proper approach. This is how OOP works. Do you understand the idea?

Comment: Yes.. I have already start working on it.. Thanks a log Andrey. Let me try this

Comment: How about upvoting my answer? I can change its content according to what we've discussed here